# What combination of Poincare generators can be used to transform to a uniformly accelerating frame?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, acceleration, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry

Is there a combination of Poincare generators which can be used to transform from an inertial frame in Minkowski space to a uniformly accelerating frame? i.e Are there some co-efficients (probably spacetime dependent in this case) $\omega_{\mu\nu}(x)$ and $a^{\mu}(x)$
\begin{equation}
\exp\Bigg(i\Big(\omega_{\mu\nu}(x)\hat{J}^{\mu\nu}+a_{\mu}(x)\hat{P}^{\mu}\Big)\Bigg),
\end{equation}
where $\hat{J}^{\mu\nu}, \hat{P}^{\mu}$ are the Lorentz and translation generators respectively, such that the action of this operator maps an inertial frame to a uniformly accelerating frame?

If the question is ill-posed as it stands, then a refinement would be, consider a particle at rest at the origin with worldline parameterization $x^{\mu}(\tau)=(\tau,0,0,0)$. Can one use the Poincare generators to transform this particle to a frame where it's parameterization reads $x^{\mu}(\tau)=\big(\cosh(a\tau),0,0,\sinh(a\tau)\big)$?

Comment: See the derivation for Rindler coordinates. For uniformly accelerating frame, you have to consider a set S of infinitely many inertial frames, each with a different velocity such that velocity of accelerating frame at a specific time will coincide with one of the inertial frame from S